# AllowAnonymous not working with ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following authentication configuration in ASP.NET Core 6.0, with a custom authentication scheme:

```cs
// Enable authentication, add a custom scheme and set it as the default
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
        opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Custom")
    .AddScheme<CustomAuthSchemeOptions, CustomAuthSchemeHandler>("Custom", null);

// stuff...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Use attribute routing for the Web API
app.MapControllers();
```

Options are empty, while the `CustomAuthSchemeHandler` can be something as simple as this:

```cs
public class CustomAuthSchemeHandler: AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthSchemeOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthSchemeHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected async override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticating..."); // the logger, yeah yeah...
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity("Test"));
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Custom");
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }
}
```

Now, what I understand (although apparently undocumented) is that **if I set the default authentication scheme** as in the code above, **authentication is automatically enforced on all controllers and actions**.

Now what if I wanted to have a **controller/action with no authentication**?

My understanding is that there are two options:

- Remove the default authentication scheme and use the `[Authorize]` attribute explicitly where needed
- Use the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to disable authentication in specific contexts

The first option works, but I can't get the `[AllowAnonymous]` approach to work.

The following code behaves as if the `[AllowAnonymous]` wasn't there, i.e. the authentication scheme handler is called anyway and the user is authenticated.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("test")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    public string Get()
    {
        return HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "YES" : "NO";
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Allow anonymous "allows anonymous" as its name implies, but also allows authorization, that's why your handler is called... it should work even when your handler can't authenticate (that's what the attribute does on the middleware)

Comment: Ah, I definitely misunderstood what it does. I thought it affected authentication but it actually undoes the effect of authorization, i.e. the `[Authorize]` attribute I didn't even use (my example has no authentication failure so I didn't notice I needed it...). Thanks for the reply, that was helpful. Feel free to put your thoughts in an answer or I'll do it later myself.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Jcl's answer, that pointed me in the right direction, here's a summary of how to use authentication schemes and authorization in ASP.NET Core 6.0.

This is an excerpt from the [blog post](https://blog.contrini.it/aspnet-core-authentication-schemes/) I've written after this question.

> - you can define many authentication schemes, whose handlers contain the actual authentication code
> - if you choose a default authentication scheme...
>
>   - the authentication handler will be called at each request, no matter what
>   - to actually enforce authorization, use `RequireAuthorization()` or `[Require]`
>   - to selectively disable authorization where already enabled, use `[AllowAnonymous]`
> - if you don't set a default scheme...
>
>   - you must explicitly choose an authentication scheme when enabling authorization, with `[Require(AuthenticationSchemes = "...")]`
>   - the authentication handler will then be run only where you enabled authorization
>   - to simplify the syntax and simply use `[Authorize]`, define a default authorization policy at startup

**UPDATE:** in ASP.NET Core 7.0, the behavior slightly [changed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/default-authentication-scheme) with respect to 6.0. If you only have one authentication scheme, it will be selected as the default one automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The `AllowAnonymous` attribute "allows anonymous" as its name implies, but also allows authorization, that's why your handler is called... it should work even when your handler can't authenticate (that's what the attribute does on the middleware)

PS: It also makes the middleware ignore the `Authorize` attribute if both are present, but not the default authentication scheme

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into this issue using a custom AuthenticationHandler supporting both JWT + API Key auth.

Adding some code in support of mcont's answer for anyone who needs an example.

In my CombinedAuthenticationHandler.cs, you can see first I check if the endpoint has the [AllowAnonymous] attribute.

Full example can be found here:
https://github.com/CodeFontana/ApiAuthDemos

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "CombinedPolicy";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CombinedPolicy";
})
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, CombinedAuthenticationHandler>("CombinedPolicy", _ => { })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
            // Token validation params
        };
    })
    .AddApiKey<ApiKeyAuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("JwtPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    });

    options.AddPolicy("ApiKeyPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    });

    options.AddPolicy("CombinedPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("CombinedPolicy");
    });
});
...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...
```

CombinedAuthenticationHandler.cs:

```
public class CombinedAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public CombinedAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
                                         ILoggerFactory logger,
                                         UrlEncoder encoder,
                                         ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Check for [AllowAnonymous] decorator on the endpoint
        Endpoint endpoint = Context.GetEndpoint();
        
        if (endpoint != null)
        {
            IAllowAnonymous allowAnonymous = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>();

            if (allowAnonymous != null)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
            }
        }

        // Try JWT Bearer authentication first
        AuthenticateResult jwtResult = await Context.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // If JWT authentication is successful, return the result
        if (jwtResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return jwtResult;
        }

        // If JWT is present but invalid, fail authentication
        if (jwtResult.Failure is SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail(jwtResult.Failure);
        }

        // If JWT authentication fails, try API Key authentication
        AuthenticateResult apiKeyResult = await Context.AuthenticateAsync(ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // If API Key authentication is successful, return the result
        if (apiKeyResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return apiKeyResult;
        }

        // Authentication failed
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Not authorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask about JWT. Your example could be much simpler if you left that part out. You only need to check for `IAllowAnonymous`, i.e. only the first lines of `HandleAuthenticateAsync()`. But thanks for the anwer, it helped.

Comment: @TsahiAsher, happy my answer helped.  In my experience, best to provide a complete example, then just a small snippet.  Everyone is at different levels; therefore, the most complete answer is best.  Whether you needed 9 lines and someone else needed 100 lines, I'd rather the complete answer be available for all.

Comment: @BrianFontana i appreciate your complete answer.  i need to bypass jwt using allowanon attribute in minimal api for a specific endpoint. your solution here will work perfect for me with minor changes inside IEndpointFilter. thanks again.